# AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'data' for merging two sorted linked lists

Tags: python, linked-list

What should I fix below?

```
# Linked List Class

class LL_Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = LL_Node(data)
        if (self.head):
            curr = self.head
            while(curr.next):
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = new_node
        else:
            self.head = new_node

    def print_LL(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            print(curr.data, end=' ')
            curr = curr.next


def merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(sorted_LL1, sorted_LL2):
    if sorted_LL1 is None:
        return sorted_LL2
    if sorted_LL2 is None:
        return sorted_LL1
    if sorted_LL1.data < sorted_LL2.data:
        sorted_LL1.next = merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(sorted_LL1.next, sorted_LL2)
        return sorted_LL1.next
    else:
        sorted_LL2.next = merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(sorted_LL1, sorted_LL2.next)
        return sorted_LL2.next

ll1 = LinkedList()
ll1.insert(1)
ll1.insert(4)
ll1.insert(6)
ll1.insert(9)
ll1.print_LL()

ll2 = LinkedList()
ll2.insert(3)
ll2.insert(4)
ll2.insert(5)
ll2.insert(10)
ll2.print_LL()

print(merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(ll1, ll2))
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-213d987ec849> in <module>()
----> 1 print(merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(ll1, ll2))

<ipython-input-65-97d65effe0a8> in merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(sorted_LL1, sorted_LL2)
     49     if sorted_LL2 is None:
     50         return sorted_LL1
---> 51     if sorted_LL1.data < sorted_LL2.data:
     52         sorted_LL1.next = merge_two_sorted_LL_recursive(sorted_LL1.next, sorted_LL2)
     53         return sorted_LL1.next

AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `sorted_LL1.data < sorted_LL2.data` comparison, you are trying to compare `data` of `LinkedList`s. However `LinkedList` class does not have `data` field. Thus, you should change that comparison to be done on `LLNode`s instead. Try `sorted_LL1[0].data < sorted_LL2[0].data`.